# Preventing bad data insertion in Node with NoSQL Database

Tags: ajax, security, node.js, nosql

Let's say we have a simple node JS backend, paired with a standard NoSQL document store such as CouchDB. Since our database is just a document key-store with no schema, anything can get inserted.  And since our server is built on JSON as well, ultimately POST requests that come in from the client with JSON payloads end up getting stored directly into our data store.

This of course is very convenient and makes for a lightweight application. I've been wondering, though, short of writing code for every possible insertion endpoint to verify that each POST or PUT request is well-formed, is there anything to prevent an attacker from firing up their developer console and spoofing POST/PUT requests, allowing them to insert any kind of junk data they wish into our datastore?  It would not be too difficult to wreck an application's data this way.

Clearly token-based authentication can ensure that only authenticated users can access these service endpoints, but that doesn't prevent them from spoofing these request with the same HTTP headers that valid requests have.  This is all quite simple with today's browser developer tools.

In a traditional server language like Java, JSON PUTs and POSTs are marshalled to a highly-structured class-based Object.  Requests whose payloads do NOT match these formats are rejected with HTTP errors.

Does anyone know of tools or paradigms for node which ensures that requests like this meet some basic structure criteria?

Comment: You cannot have it both ways. Either you validate the data or your don't. If you don't validate it then you run into the risk that you mentioned. The kind of validation that you need will depend on your application.

Comment: If you are using CouchDB, you have built-in [document validation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Validation) at your disposal.